# Bijective holomorphic map with a fixed point

Tags: complex-analysis

$f$ be a holomorphic on a bounded domain $D$ with  fixed point $z_0$. Could any one give a hint how to show the following:

$f$ is bijective iff $|f'(z_0)|=1$.

Well, I was thinking like to compose $f,f^2,\dots,f^n$ and apply some how $f^n$ also has $z_0$ as fixed point. Thank you for help.

Comment: the question as stated isn't true: consider f(z) = z^2; then f(1) = 1, , f'(1) = 2 but f is not bijective. do you need your fixed point to be unique?

Comment: yes then, I hope, edited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not true.  Consider $f(z) = z + z^2$ on $D = \mathbb C$.  The unique fixed point is $0$, $f'(0) = 1$, but $f(-1-z) = f(z)$.

Comment: if the uniqueness of fixed point withdrawn?

Comment: and is your map bijective?

Comment: No, the fact that $f(-1-z) = f(z)$ shows that $f$ is not bijective on any domain that contains both $z$ and $-1-z$ for some $z$.

Comment: I am extremely sorry Dear Sir, I have edited my question.

Comment: Adding the requirement of "bounded domain" does not fix the question.  As I said, my example is not bijective on any domain that contains both $z$ and $-1-z$ for some $z$.

Comment: It's not stated in the question, but from considering the iterates of $f$, it seems that the intention is that $f \colon D \to D$ is a holomorphic self-map of the bounded domain $D$, and in that case, the conclusion holds. If $D \subset \mathbb{C}$ is a bounded domain, $f\colon D\to D$ holomorphic with a fixed point $z_0\in D$, then $f$ is bijective if and only if $\lvert f'(z_0)\rvert = 1$. (cc @BunuelianTrick)